# Moving from Zoho Apps to Google Apps

Tags: google-app-maker

I am looking to move my Zoho created app into Google App maker. Reason being I already have an Enterprise subscription and I do not want to pay multiple subscriptions.

Please advise?

I am not a developer. My app was developed in Zoho by an expert.

Answer (score 1):

Google app maker is being disabled at the beginning of next year and you shouldn't be able to make any new apps at this point.